# Copying data from one table to another between two SQL Server instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an application that uses a remote database connection as a source (SQL Server), but the database table is case sensitive, and I need it not to be. To solve this I am looking to keep a local copy of that table. Values are regularly added and removed from the source table, so I need the local table to be kept up to date, hourly. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you just create case insensitive views?

Comment: Why do you need it not to be? You can apply a collation on a join, view, and where clause... this would far easier than database mirroring, log shipping, etc (what you are trying to do in your thread)

Comment: What version of SQL? I think you can just change the collation in your query to a non-case-sensitive collation to get what you need.

Comment: You could use a persisted view and refresh that persisted view whenever is needed.

Comment: Thanks to all. The case insensitive view did the trick!